# Can't respond to Alexa Unhandled Intent

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

My Unhandled Intent is specified as follows:

```
'Unhandled': function() {
    console.log('#Unhandled');
    console.log('The skill will crash now :(');
    this.emit(':tell', this.t('UNHANDLED_MESSAGE'));
}
```

I can see in my logs that this function is called. However the emit-Call is completely ignored by Alexa. Instead I get a sound like "dudu" and the skill closes.

Can someone explain to me how I can use this function to tell something to the user, instead of closing the skill?

Comment: Does this Unhandled is triggered when some exception occur in your lambda function ?

Comment: There are no exceptions logged in Lambda when this happens.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but is this.t maybe not matching something? If you just emit text like `this.emit(':tell', 'this is unhandled');` does it respond?

Comment: this.t is matched, I already tried plain text but that also didn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

I had similar experience, but in my case 'Unhandled' is not called, and my skill is closed with "dudu" sound.

I could not find official document to explain it, but 'Unhandled' is called when you use "state" in your script.
If I use state in my script, then 'Unhandled' is called.

This is a blog refering state in Alexa skills.
https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/Tx213D2XQIYH864/announcing-the-alexa-skills-kit-for-node-js